# JSF2: Ajax Request and Site Navigation

Tags: jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I'm just finishing Balusc's JSF2 Tutorial, and I am running into a problem with the ajax request sent by the blur event on input components.

My page is set up with a general sidebar, which contains `h:link` to my different views.
In one of my views, I use code like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputLabel value="title" for="unitTitle"/>
    <h:inputText id="unitTitle" value="#{unitOverview.unit.title}" label="title">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="unitMessage"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="unitMessage" for="unitTitle"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So when I am navigating to a different site, while using one of the input components, I get an `http` error, because of the `ajax request` and the full request sent to the server at the same time...

I'm new to `JSF`, so these options come into my mind for solving this issue:

1. disable the blur event
2. create another sidebar component, using ajax links - and getting
   the different links for the view from an application scopes managed
   bean

I kind of dislike both options, is there another option I'm not thinking of? How do "real world" applications solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any further with the problem described above?

Comment: Oh, kind of forgot about this post, due to the fact that I had no time for learning more JSF.
Actually your answer didn't resolve this topic, I still have unwanted behaviour.
e.g. when I just tab through the input fields, the message should be displayed.
e.g. when I write something in the input field, switch to another field, switch back to the old one again, delete the input and click on another link, I still have the problem I had at the beginning :(

I want the exact behaviour from blur, just without the ajax error :/

Answer (score 0):

you are right, sending an ajax- and a normal http request parallel is not a good idea.

Well, try to use a `change` instead of the `blur`. It will be also triggered when leaving the input field but should only trigger when there was a real change.

Also, it might be a good idea, to update your question with the xhtml holding a minimized version of your complete problem (including `<h:form>`) to make the problem easier understandable and testable in possible interested users IDE. :-)

Hope it helps...